# Is there a term for the belief that nothing exists?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Monism is the belief that only one thing exists. Is there a term for the belief that nothing exists, and have any serious philosophers given any arguments for that belief?

Comment: The closest idea is metaphysical nihilism, but even it is usually interpreted modally, as in nothing *could have* existed, see [SEP, Nothingness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/).

Comment: Somebody made that argument. So something exists as Yuri said in the answer.

Comment: Imagine the kind of semantic gymnastics you would need to even pursue such a statement. The word “exist” would have to be reduced to a meaningless definition.

Comment: I would argue does not truly make a unique assertion, but only redefines either nothing, or exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Offering such an argument -- that nothing exists -- would be self-contradictory: doing so necessitates the existence of *at least* two things a) the argument itself, and b) someone making it.

A serious philosopher would see that -- otherwise, they *objectively* aren't.

Comment: What does it mean for an argument to exist?

Comment: It means there is a record of it, something physical. The same is true for any information, including yourself -- there must some record of your mind, somewhere... Plus some information processing hardware that "runs" you.

Comment: There's a record of it, such as it being written down on a piece of paper? But an argument, if it exists, is not scribbling on a piece of paper, just as the number 2, if it exists, is not identical to (same as) any scribbling of the numeral on any piece of paper, blackboard, etc. If these things exist, they exist as abstract objects. But there are lots of reasons to think abstracts objects don't exist....

Comment: .... So I think you can only reasonably conclude that there exists someone offering an argument, which is enough to establish that something exists (this is along the lines of Descartes), not that there is this abstract object called an argument.

Comment: Why paper, seriously? I said there is a physical record of you, just as well -- you think I meant you're a book that would run on... IBM 370 I guess, 'cause punch cards...

Comment: No, I'm still talking about arguments. What would be a physical record of it and how could an argument be identical to its physical record? The question is rhetorical, by the way, because an argument can't possibly be identical to anything physical since, if it exists, it is can abstract object. But as I said, the existence of abstract objects is not at all established; some philosopher's maintain that there are no abstract objects and therefore no such things as arguments.

Comment: Anyway, physical record ≠ notebook. Could be memory chips in your phone, hard-drive, neurons in your brain, or DNA, DNA goes w/o saying...  or a black hole can store a lot (though i keep getting reports about Hawkins radiation being unipressed with John 1:3, wtf?.. or John 1:5, like literally...) Point is, information = 1/entropy -- scribe 2 with galaxy clusters for all i care :) I don't believe in abstract objects either.

Comment: So then arguments don't exist.

Comment: of course they do! -- that's what neurons for.. also for the "abstract" objects -- like i have my own concept of 2, just as you do... the reason it appears to us like it is far up above everything (behind CMB, up from clouds in early days) is that normally, being in agreement on a subject makes it... into an object?... like it's a part of the objective reality, and NOT in your head <== and that's like the most sacred human truth, the cornerstone of our faith in humanity and in ourselves  <==  NOT a joke

Comment: That's why we would rather have a (relatively harmless) "abstract object" illusion than potentially undermine that sacred trust, our only line to reality... it alone keeps us from going insane... We must depend on others for our own sanity... a hard pill to swallow.